# PHP, SQL Server: Using binary data with stored procedures

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

PHP 5.2.13, MS SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoreThing]
    @pid int = 0,
    @data binary(236) = NULL,
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO thingTable (pid, data) VALUES (@pid, @data)
END
```

(Greatly simplified, but that's beside the point)

I'm trying to call this procedure from a PHP script, as such:

```
function storeThing($pid, $data) {
    global $dbconn;

    if(strlen($data) != 236) return false;

    $proc = mssql_init('StoreThing', $dbconn);

    mssql_bind($proc, '@pid', $pid, SQLINT4);
    mssql_bind($proc, '@data', $data, SQLCHAR, false, false, 236);

    $result = mssql_execute($proc);
    if(!$result) die(mssql_get_last_message());

    return true;
}
```

However, this is not working quite right. I get the following error when I run it:

```
Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: message: Implicit conversion from data type char to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (severity 16)
```

Obviously, the problem is the `SQLCHAR` type I set for the data field. However, since there is no SQLBINARY constant, I am not sure what to set it to.

Alternately, will I have to change the stored procedure to accommodate PHP? I could do that, but it seems a bit dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft SQL Server API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Ah. At the time I wrote this question, I didn't know there was a new extension for this. I ended up modifying the stored procedure anyway (and porting the app to ASP.NET, but that's beside the point)